# select 1st option in a multi group dropdown with jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, optgroup

I have dropdown very similar to this:

```
<select id='someSelect'>
    <option value="0">---select one---</option>
    <optgroup label="Bikes">
        <option value="B-4">Hayabusa</option>
        <option value="B-2">GSXR</option>
        <option value="B-3">Ninja</option>
        <option value="B-6">Enticer</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Cars"> 
        <option value="C-4">Audi TT</option>
        <option value="C-2">Awesome Car</option>
        <option value="C-23">Japanese car</option>
        <option value="C-9">German car</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I just want to select the 1st element of 1st group (bikes here). How do I go about it in jQuery please?

Currently, I tried this:

```
$('#someSelect option:nth-child(1)').attr("selected", "selected");
```

**BUT**, the trouble is, since there are three 1st elements ( `--select--`, `Hayabusa` and `Audi TT`) it selects all three, which finaly selects `Audi TT`

I tried to do some stuff with `each` and select just the second one, but then I realized that the dropdown is dynamic, I don't want to select the default one (which is `--select one--`) but the **first element of first group**

I tried to mock up a jsfiddle, but it's mucked up and not working, not sure why :-/
 [you can see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nYd67/)

Comment: Please avoid profanity, it sets off net nannies that block people from using SO at work, and tends to offend people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/x6H22/3/) is an example and here is the selector I used:

```
$("#someSelect optgroup option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
```

As you can see, I used the first option by looking inside the optgroup element.

Comment: aa this looks obvious.. sometimes my dropdown doesn't have any optgroup at all and it works great on that! though I do not understand how.. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

Well this works:

http://jsfiddle.net/nYd67/1/

```
$(function(){
    $('#someSelect optgroup:eq(0) option:eq(0)').attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

select from the optgroup instead of the select:

```
$('optgroup[label=Bikes] option:first')
```

Or, if you don't want to specify the label, just filter on the optgroup as well:

```
$('optgroup:first option:first')
```

Answer (score 3):

Just include the optgroup in your selector:

```
$('#someSelect optgroup:nth-child(2) option:nth-child(1)')
```

Just remember that the `:nth-child()` selector is 1-based, not 0-based. Also, in this case, you don't even need to qualify the selector with a tag name, so it could also be just:

```
$('#someSelect :nth-child(2) :nth-child(1)')
```

Answer (score 2):

I always find that `.eq()` is a lot easier to use. This seems to work correctly in your jsfiddle.

```
$('#someSelect option').eq(1).attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#someSelect optgroup:first option:first').attr('selected', true);
```

this works, I have tested on your html

Answer (score 1):

The selector for the first `option` in the first `optgroup` of the `select` element with an id of "someSelect":

```
"select#someSelect > optgroup:nth-child(1) > option:nth-child(1)"
```

Comment: yes, this made me understand the theory behind it, thank you so much!